# express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) does not work even when expresion change

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm trying to return a JSON on my POST for my Express App.

I recived the error "express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body)" but even when i change the line with the error it stills shows the same error.

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "Email",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/cognitiveservices-face": "^4.2.0",
    "@azure/ms-rest-js": "^2.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.0"
  }
}
```

The names that i use for express:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

The code that i'm trying to get a successful responce is:

```
app.post("/analisis/faceid", (req, res) => {
  let img = req.body.img;

  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: endpoint_faceID,
    params: {
      detectionModel: "detection_03",
      returnFaceId: true,
    },
    data: {
      url: img,
    },
    headers: {
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": Ocp_Apim_Subscription_Key,
    },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      let response_data = {
          mgs: "OK",
        faceId: response.data[0].faceId
      };
      res.send(response_data); //HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR APPEARS 
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      res.send("ERROR AT FACE ID : ", error);
    });
});
```

I have tried replace it with:

```
res.json(response_data)
res.jsonp(200, response_data)
res.status(200).send(response_data)
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response_data))
res.status(200).json(response_data)
res.status(200).jsonp(response_data)
```

But i keep getting the same error.

PD: sorry for my English

Comment: Changing it to `res.json(response_data)` (and restarting the server afterwards) should avoid the error.

Comment: Thanks, but i already use that and got the same error :(

Comment: Could it be that the error message occurs on the line `res.send("ERROR AT FACE ID : ", error);` where you call `res.send` with *two* arguments? If you replace that with `res.send(error);`, you will see the underlying error. For example, this could be a failure of the `axios` post request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone.

The problem was the 2 arguments that i tryed to pass on the catch

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).